# Errors display with php

Tags: php

I've read lots of posts here about that but found nothing that worked for me!
I need to have php errors displayed on browser for one site. All other site must not. In my php.ini I've

```
error_reporting = E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

and

```
display_errors = On
```

On My .htaccess I've

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

I've tried to put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

on the starting of my php script I need to debug, but always I've an error, there is a blank page, and not errors. Nothing more in the log file on the server... I don't understand how to have these errors displayed... Any idea please?

[edit]
Starting of my php script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once("config.php");
include_once("include/functions.php");

function main(){
global $link;
include("header.php");

echo '
<!-- Our Services -->
```

Comment: Might be worth including 10 or so lines of the code in your script too. I tend to use only two lines at the start of each script: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)`. Give those a go.

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` report as *effective* values?

Comment: dunc: doesn't work...
Alvaro: yes, I've just checked and the values are ok

Comment: Set error reporting to on at ini level - might be something during compile that is breaking. Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Comment: But I just want the errors for 1 site, not others on the server

Answer (score 1):

You could try.

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: Please check phpinfo(); and check if the values are changed.

Comment: display_errors On
error_reporting 8192
track_errors Off
error_append_string no value
error_log no value
error_prepend_string no value
error_reporting 8192

Comment: after adding lines only one value change: error_reporting 32767

Comment: 32767 error_reporting is the same as E_ALL, so that should work.
Well lets check if .htacces file can make some changes
.htacces:
php_value error_reporting -1  (-1 stands for complete error reporting)

# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log

Comment: Finaly I was successful. I put the code in each php script called from the first one and I have now error messages...

Answer (score 0):

put this on top of your php page.

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```